# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is not allowed access. Response HTTP 401

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp, rpc, json-rpc

```
var url = "http://www.api.sitehoover.com/api/";
var request = {};
request.id = "1";
request.method = "add_page";
request.params = "a7eede94cdc5e5aa77bd8db969ab0089";
request.params.folder_oid = "9";
request.params.url = "http://www.google.com/";
request.params.title = "My Google Page";
request.jsonrpc = "2.0";

function displaySearchResult(response) {
alert("In displaySearchResult.... ");
    if (response.result)
            alert(response.result);

    else if (response.error)
            alert("Search error: " + response.error.message);
};

$.post(url, JSON.stringify(request), displaySearchResult, "json");`
```

Am trying JSON RPC call. When I checked Chrome console, I found:
[image]

Even in Mozilla console, it says 401 authorization error.
When I started digging about this error, I hit into 'Single domain Policy' and other stuff which quoted that adding header for accepting the calls from origin domain or using **JSONP** resolved the issue.

I tried them too but to no vail. Can someone help with the JSONP?

Comment: If the server does not support JSONP or CORS, you simply cannot use browser JavaScript to directly access it.

Comment: Server (http://www.sitehoover.com/en/api/) accepts it. Even then its throwing this error. AM not sure how to go forward.

Comment: Ah well, you cannot make POST requests without CORS. JSONP only works with GET requests.

Comment: So if I want to use the API that they are exposing, how do I do it?

Comment: Putting aside CORS for a minute, you're constructing the `params` field in the json-rpc packet incorrectly. `params` should be an `Array` (not a `String`) according to the example. Something like: `request.params = ["a7eede94cdc5e5aa77bd8db969ab0089", { "folder_oid": "9", "url": "http://www.google.com/", "title": "My Google Page"}]; `